# Render happens before state is set

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react and cant solve the problem which i m facing. The initial render does not detect data as set state is is still loading data. I am checking that with a condition but still the error message is displayed and then playtests load. Can you guys please help ?

```
export default class PlaytestsIndex extends React.Component {
    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this._onPlaytestStoreChange = this._onPlaytestStoreChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            playtests: PlaytestStore.getActivePlaytests()
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        PlaytestStore.addChangeListener(this._onPlaytestStoreChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
    PlaytestStore.addChangeListener(this._onPlaytestStoreChange);
    }

    _onPlaytestStoreChange () {
     this.setState({
     playtests: PlaytestStore.getActivePlaytests()
        });
    }

    render () {
        const playtests = this.state.playtests;
        if (playtests.length === 0) {
            return (
                <table className="table table-fixed content-section">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr className="disabled">
                        <td className="no-results center">No playtests found</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            )
        };
        const today = Moment().minute(0).hour(0).second(0).millisecond(0);
        // how the groups of playtests are sorted
        const sortOrderLabels = [
            'Currently Active',
            'Upcoming'
        ];
        const timelineDateRows = _.chain(playtests)
            .groupBy((playtest) => {
                const startsOn = Moment(playtest._startsOnDateTime).minute(0).hour(0).second(0).millisecond(0);
                if (today.isAfter(startsOn) || today.isSame(startsOn, 'day')) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return 1;
            })
            .toPairs() // [[idx, playtests], ...]
            .sortBy((paired) => paired[0]) // by idx
            .map((paired) => {
                const [idx, playtests] = paired;
                return (<TimelineDateRow key={sortOrderLabels[idx]} label={sortOrderLabels[idx]} playtests={playtests}/>);
            })
            .value();
        return (
            <div>
                {timelineDateRows}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: is `PlaytestStore.getActivePlaytests()` async operation ? i mean if it wait for response of some web-api ?

Comment: You might need to trigger the inital load `action` on `componentDidMount`. example `componentDidMount() { PlaytestActions.loadActivePlaytests() }`.. Also check the store is emitting the change event correctly. And lastly in your willUnmount i think you mean to use `removeChangeListener`

Comment: On React's lifecycle `componentDidMount()` is executed after `render()`. You might use `componentWillMount()`, that gets executed before `render()`.

Comment: getActivePlaytests gets the active list of id's from db and is workign gine as the id's do load after two seconds. I tried to trigger the inital load action but no luck still the error is displayed for two seconds and then the id's show up on screen. I did try to use componentwillMount but still the same error. Thanks in advance